# Im trying to make a tax calculator for my coursework but im stuck hoplefull someone can help because ive got no clue (Java)

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoomTaxSystem {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
        try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rooms.txt"))){
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileLines.add(currentLine);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

            Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = "";
            do {
                double taxRate = 20.0;
                System.out.print("Specify Custom Tax Rate [Y|N]: ");
                input = inputScanner.next();
                double TaxRate = inputScanner.nextDouble();
                if(input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y")) {
                    boolean invalidInput;
                    do {
                        invalidInput = true;
                        try {
                            System.out.print("Specify Tax Rate (%): ");
                            taxRate = Double.valueOf(inputScanner.next());
                            invalidInput = false;
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Input must be a valid double value.");
                        }
                    } while(invalidInput);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Assuming Tax Rate = " + taxRate + "%");
                }

                double totalIncome = 0.0;
                double totalTaxes = 0.0;

                for(int roomIndex = 0; roomIndex < fileLines.size() / 3; roomIndex++) {
                    String roomType = fileLines.get(roomIndex * 3); 
                    int bookings = Integer.valueOf(fileLines.get((roomIndex * 3) + 1)); 
                    double roomPrice = Double.valueOf(fileLines.get((roomIndex * 3) + 2)); 
                    double income = bookings * roomPrice; 
                    double taxes = income * (taxRate / 100); 
                    totalIncome += income; 
                    totalTaxes += taxes; 

                    System.out.printf("Room Type : %s, Bookings : %d, Room Price : £%.2f, Income : £%.2f, Tax : £%.2f\n", roomType, bookings, roomPrice, income, taxes);
                }

                System.out.printf("Total Income : £%.2f\n", totalIncome);
                System.out.printf("Total Taxes : £%.2f\n", totalTaxes);
                System.out.print("Rerun the program? [Y|N]: ");
                input = inputScanner.next();
            } while(input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error when reading the \"rooms.txt\" file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Single 5 23.50

Double 3 27.50

Suite 2 50.00
^Numbers above are the Appendix A I need to use for the tax calculator but cant figure where ive gone wrong all help will be appreciated If not its fine I just cant seem figure it out this is what it should do upon application launch, the system should ask the managers if they wish to specify a custom tax rate, this should be in the form of a yes / no question. When the managers say yes, the system should request the tax rate as input (from the keyboard) which will then overwrite the default tax rate (i.e. Appendix B). When the managers say no, the system should report (to the screen) the default tax rate (i.e. Appendix C). Next, the system should loop through the room’s data, calculating and printing (to the screen) the room type, number of bookings, room price, income before tax and tax, the latter two requiring some basic calculations. Finally, the running totals for the income before tax and tax should be calculated and printed before the system gracefully exits. This is what happens when I click run

```
    Specify Custom Tax Rate [Y|N]: y
Y
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at RoomTaxSystem.main(RoomTaxSystem.java:26)
```

Comment: Your question looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729054/how-to-use-a-while-loop-to-read-from-text-file ?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is here :

double TaxRate = inputScanner.nextDouble();

you are using the get next double method against a string

Comment: How would I fix that? Because im lost hahaha

Comment: Ive changed it to this not sure if its right String TaxRate = inputScanner.toString();but now its popped up Specify Custom Tax Rate [Y|N]: Y
Specify Tax Rate (%): 20
Room Type : Single, Bookings : Exception in thread "main" 5, Room Price : £23.50, Income : £117.50, Tax : £23.50
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Double"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
 at RoomTaxSystem.main(RoomTaxSystem.java:48)