# how to use a while loop to read from text file

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to be able to read 3 separate blocks of text from a file and display them including the calculations to the console using a while loop. At the moment I can only get one block of text to display.

I couldn't figure out how to format it on here exactly like it is in the text file so excuse the image.
[Text File:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZGFe.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileReader input = new FileReader ("rooms.txt");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner read = new Scanner (input);
    final double defaultTax = .20;
    
    
    System.out.println("Do you wish to specify a custom tax rate? (yes/no): ");
    
     if (console.next().equals("yes")) {
         System.out.println("What would you like the tax rate to be?");
     }      
    //use while loop
     
    else
     {

        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
        
        String roomType = read.nextLine();
        int rooms = read.nextInt();
        double price = read.nextDouble();
        double totalIncome = (double) (rooms*price);
        double tax = (double) (price*rooms*defaultTax);
    System.out.println("Room type: " + roomType + " | No. of rooms: " + rooms + " | Room price: " + price + " | income: " + totalIncome + " | tax: " + tax);
        }
     }
}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT: Room type: Single | No. of rooms: 5 | Room price: 23.5 | income: 117.5 | tax: 23.5

The desired output would include all of the data, including the calculations.

```
Current error message:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at cwk/cwk.test1.main(test1.java:31)
```

I am literally just a uni student looking for a bit of help on a bit of one module. I'm not a programmer, I'm not doing a programming course. please don't delete my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to whitespace. When you call `nextLine` it will read a whole line, until it encounters `\n` or the end of the file. When you call `nextInt` and `nextDouble` it will skip any preceding whitespace, however it will not consume any whitespace after.

So the first iteration of your while loop is working fine. However the next iteration when `nextLine` is called, then an empty string is returned. After that when `nextInt` is called, then it encounters `"Double"` and thus you get an `InputMismatchException`.

The easiest way to fix this, is that at the end of your while loop, you can skip all subsequent whitespace:

```java
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    // Keep everything you already have

    read.skip("\\s+");
}
```